# Make: How to store result of a command in a macro?

Tags: linux, macros, makefile, command

I have a makefile that doesn't do much yet:

```
SRCS = *FOR

OBJS = $(SRCS:.FOR=.o)

tell_srcs: $(SRCS)
    echo $(SRCS)

tell_objs:  $(OBJS)
    echo $(OBJS)
```

`make tell_srcs` operates as I hoped, returning

```
file1.FOR file2.FOR file3.FOR ....
```

However, `make tell_objs` returns the exact same thing:

```
file1.FOR file2.FOR file3.FOR ....
```

which is not what I expected nor need.

I guess the point is that make is not really storing the results of `*FOR` in $(SRCS), but is storing the actual `*FOR` "command" in $(SRCS), and the substitution I tried to do to get $(OBJS) has no effect ... I guess.  Anyway, is there a way to get make to store the actual output of `*FOR` in $(SRCS) so it will function as a regular macro?  Thanks.

BTW, here's version info:

```
 >make -v
 GNU Make 3.81
```

Comment: best to include results of `make --version` or `make -v` or version listed when you look at man page. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SRCS = $(shell echo *FOR)

OBJS = $(SRCS:.FOR=.o)

tell_srcs: $(SRCS)
    echo $(SRCS)

tell_objs:  $(OBJS)
    echo $(OBJS)
```

The `SRCS = *.FOR` sets SRCS to `*.FOR`, not the shell-expanded result of *.FOR.  So, when OBJS is processed it tries to change `.FOR` at the end of `*FOR`.  I suspect you tried `*.FOR` in SRCS and ran into the problem that the use of OBJS gave `*.o` or the list of all `.o` files in the directory.

`make -p` can help in these cases, although I suspect this case would still have been a mystery.

Comment: Actually, when $(OBJS) is in the dependency list, I get the message -- to be expected, I suppose -- that there is no rule to make file1.o etc. But when I take that out, I do get `file1.o file2.o file3.o ...` which is what I was hoping for. Thanks for the tip!